# aspnetboilerplate failing stress test with transactional UoW

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-sql-database, aspnetboilerplate, stress-testing

The stress test consists of calling the following API 500 times concurrently:

```
    [UnitOfWork(IsDisabled = true)]
    [AbpAllowAnonymous]
    public async Task StressTest(string input)
    {
        using (var uow = UnitOfWorkManager.Begin
            (
            new UnitOfWorkOptions
            {
                Scope = System.Transactions.TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew,
                IsTransactional = true,
                IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted,
                AsyncFlowOption = System.Transactions.TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled
            })
            )
        {
            var data = await _userRepository.GetAll()
                .Where(x => x.EmailAddress == input)
                .Select(x => new { x.FirstName, x.CreationTime, x.IsDeleted })
                .AsNoTracking()
                .ToListAsync();

            await uow.CompleteAsync();
        }
    }
```

Packages' versions and database:

- aspnetboilerplate v3.6.1
- aspnetcore v2.2.0
- entityframeworkcore v2.1.0
- Azure SQL

Summary:

- The whole application becomes unresponsive without returning any of the requests. Any http request to the app that results in using sql will hang until it times out.
- The test succeeds with non-transactional UoW.
- The query takes 50ms when executed outside the stress test
- The test was done on production and local environment.
- None of the below mentioned resources were capped or reached its limit.
- Auditing is disabled.

Resources Monitored during stress test:

- CPU utilization
- Memory utilization
- Completion Threads
- Worker Threads
- SQL sessions
- SQL workers
- SQL CPU utilization
- SQL locks
- Out-bound ports

Things I have tried:

- Using the default UoW initialized by ABP.
- Stress test a custom controller instead of an App Service.
- Changing the IsolationLevel.
- Increasing the minimum and maximum number of threads in the connection thread pool.
- Increasing the minimum number of worker and completion threads.
- Not completing the UoW.
- turn pooling on/off.

The expected behavior is that ABP should be able to handle 500 concurrent update http requests for example. My only guess is something going horribly wrong with transaction management inside abp with no means to profile or debug it.

EDIT 1:

Opening transactions manually without relying on abp breezes through the stress test without any issues. As far as I understand, this eliminates any suspicions concerning Azure SQL or EFCore, it's purely an abp issue.

```
    [UnitOfWork(IsDisabled = true)]
    [AbpAllowAnonymous]
    public async Task StressTest(string input)
    {
        using (var tx = await _ctx.Database.BeginTransactionAsync(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
        {
            var data = await _ctx.Users
                    .Where(x => x.EmailAddress == input)
                    .Select(x => new { x.FirstName, x.CreationTime, x.IsDeleted })
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .ToListAsync();

            tx.Commit();
        }
    }
```

EDIT 2:

While watching open transactions inside the database, there is a difference in behavior. When opening transactions manually, the transactions never pile up in the database, they are opened and closed quickly and gradually. However, when abp is handling transactions, they pile up in the database without getting closed until abp reaches the max connection pool limit. For example, if my max pool connection is 200, then 200 transactions pile up in the database.

Here is the query used to watch open transactions

```
SELECT [s_tst].[session_id],
[database_name] = DB_NAME (s_tdt.database_id),
[s_tdt].[database_transaction_begin_time], 
[sql_text] = [s_est].[text] 
FROM sys.dm_tran_database_transactions [s_tdt]
INNER JOIN sys.dm_tran_session_transactions [s_tst] ON [s_tst]. 
[transaction_id] = [s_tdt].[transaction_id]
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections [s_ec] ON [s_ec].[session_id] 
= [s_tst].[session_id]
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text ([s_ec]. 
[most_recent_sql_handle]) AS [s_est];
```

Comment: `await uow.CompleteAsync()`?

Comment: @aaron completing the uow results in the same failed test

Comment: Your code doesn't show that.

Comment: @aaron True, but I have tested it with and without completing the uow. I left out the complete command to limit confusion about it being the cause and added it the "things I have tried" list. Anyway, I will edit the code as I get how someone might think that the missing complete is the cause. Meanwhile, could you take another look as I have added a couple of edits that might be helpful.

Comment: Did you try with just `UnitOfWorkManager.Begin()` to see whether the default options are fine?

Comment: Do you have index on `EmailAddress` column? How many records in the table?

Comment: @aaron
I tried it without [UnitOfWork(IsDisabled = true)] and allowing abp to automatically create the UoW, I assumed it would use the defaults as I haven't configured them anywhere. I will try creating the UoW manually without passing any configs to it and let you know.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv
The table is 250k+ rows and the test was done with and without an index for EmailAddress and on different tables with different conditions. Also, the test works for non-transactional UoW and manually created transactions outside UoW, pushing the database out of the picture in my opinion.

Comment: Then add index! If you have a tons of such calls - SQL Server will die.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Please read my comment again as I have explained that adding an index did not work and the reasoning for my conclusion that the problem is outside the database.